# Attachments are not visible in the sharepoint 2010 list item

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Created a list "Deploy Request" And Created a form to attach the documents to the list.

When i click "Add new item" my form is opened where i attached my files. But after saving its not visible under the column(which is the attachment icon).

But when i select the saved item and selected the option "View Item" it is there. I want the same to be visible under the attachment icon column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal List Forms instade of Custom List Forms.

If your attachment functionality is required for Display custom list form, please follow the following URL.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c257a894-859a-406c-b3bd-d021ef1b7a75/adding-attachment-field-to-data-form-web-part?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Thanks,
Arnab